# How to read arguments as numeric vector

Tags: r, rscript

I'm having some troubles with my R script, because I want to use it from a bash script. My problem comes when I call the script and introduce its arguments, I use the following command line

```
Rscript myscript.R 1,2,1,3,2,3
```

I want to use the argument "1,2,1,3,2,3" as a numeric vector in order to use its length and elements. So in myscript.R the code is:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
comparisons <- args[1]
```

but when I use this variable `comparisons` to other things it comes the error:

```
for (i in seq(from = 1, to = length(comparisons)-1, by = 2))
{
...
}
```

Error message:

```
Error in seq.default(from = 1, to = (length(comparisons) - 1), by = 2) : 
wrong sign in 'by' argument
Calls: seq -> seq.default
Execution halted
```

How can I read the argument `comparisons` as a numeric vector?

Comment: It is still run from the `r` interpreter, has nothing to do with `bash`, removing the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code, comparisions is just a one-element string vector, thus`(length(comparisons) - 1) = 0`. This causes, `from 1 -> to 0` is decreasing, but `by 2` is positive, thus seq fails.

You can use this code to convert it to a numeric vector

```
comparisons <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(comparisons, ","), as.numeric))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works fine and solves my problem!

Answer (score 3):

The `scan()` function is an oft-overlooked but highly useful and versatile tool:

```
scan(text=args[1], sep=",", quiet=TRUE)
```

If you don't need `double`s then:

```
scan(text=args[1], what=integer(), sep=",", quiet=TRUE)
```

will give you integers.